# getByteTimeDomainData (Web Audio API)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I understand that `fftSize` and `getByteTimeDomainData` are linked since the length of `fftSize` is the same as the length of the array of `getByteTimeDomainData`.

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const audioSourceNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
const analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();

analyserNode.fftSize = 256;

const bufferTimeDomainLength = analyserNode.fftSize;
console.log(bufferTimeDomainLength)
const dataTimeDomainArray = new Uint8Array(bufferTimeDomainLength);

audioSourceNode.connect(analyserNode);
analyserNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
setTimeout(loop, 1000);

function loop() {
  analyserNode.getByteTimeDomainData(dataTimeDomainArray);
  for (let i = 0; i < bufferTimeDomainLength; i++) {
    let v = dataTimeDomainArray[i];
    console.log(v + " - " + i);
  }
}
```

My big question is that it represents `v`. Is it the amplitude of that sample or is it the bin number? I've actually read the Mozilla Developers documentation but I still don't understand anything.

Comment: `const bufferTimeDomainLength = analyserNode.fftSize;` ... `analyserNode.fftSize = 256;`.  Does that help?

Comment: And then... `const dataTimeDomainArray = new Uint8Array(bufferTimeDomainLength);` ... So dataTimeDomainArray has 256 elements in it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know the length of `dataTimeDomainArray` is 256, but I want to know is that it represents each element (`v`). The amplitud?

Comment: Where did you get this code?